# Ubuntu not showing USB in file manager

Tags: 20.04, usb, filemanager, fdisk, udisks

Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS jammy Desktop

1. recognises the USB as per fdisk
2. an audio notification confirms the inserted (and removed) USB

however [file manager is missing the USB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ShwU.png)?

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sde: 3.74 GiB, 4016046080 bytes, 7843840 sectors
Disk model: Transcend 4GB   
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

My USB had a bootable Ubuntu OS, so I formated the USB with the Disks app, which set the default format as (Ext4), letting me add files on the USB.

Comment: Have you checked other locations?

Comment: Is it mounted? Do: `grep /dev/sde /etc/mtab`.Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Do not use Add Comment.

Comment: Sorry, I actually solved this by reformatting and deleting all partitions. I tried to post the solution, but StackExchange doesn't let me.